# ASP.NET MVC Remote validation and duplicate key

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-5

I ran into this problem related to remote validation. 
I have a database-first model, where I have separated the validation metadata to its own partial class (so I don't have to change the auto-generated class).

On my Email field, I want remote validation to check if e-mail exists. The problem is that

```
[Remote("CheckEmail", "Users", ErrorMessage = "E-mail exists")]
public string Email;
```

is not valid because [Remote()] only works on properties and indexer declarations. If I change it to a property in the metadata-class

```
[Remote("CheckEmail", "Users", ErrorMessage = "E-mail exists")]
public string Email { get; set; }
```

I get a "An item with the same key has already been added"-error when I run the application  because this property allready exist in the auto-generated database-first class.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Use a view model and apply the annotations to the view model property (`[Remote]` is only applicable for client side validation so does not make a lot of sense to apply it to a domain model)

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I will create a viewmodel instead!